# WCF error: Cannot find a token authenticator

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, x509certificate, http-token-authentication

i need to consume WCF service over SSL while the request needs to be sign with one certificate and the response needs to be validated with another certificate.

i get this error while executing the code:

> Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.

according to WCF tracing it fails while trying to validate the response signature, because i can see the response from the server.

### here's my WCF service settings:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
      messageFlowTracing="true" />

  </diagnostics>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CHClientCertificateBehavior">
        <clientCredentials supportInteractive="true">
          <clientCertificate findValue="clientcert" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
            storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          <serviceCertificate>
            <defaultCertificate findValue="servercert" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
          </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="DPBasicHttpBindingWithSSL" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
        textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        messageEncoding="Text">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="DPCustomHttpBindingWithSSL">
        <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"                       messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" 
                  requireDerivedKeys="false" 
                  securityHeaderLayout="Lax" />
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <httpsTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288" />
      </binding>

    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://myserver/service.asmx"
            behaviorConfiguration="CHClientCertificateBehavior" binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="DPCustomHttpBindingWithSSL" contract="ServiceRef.smssoap"
            name="smsEndpoint">
            <identity>
                <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                    x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="myserver" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>

    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

as you can see, i tried both basicHttpBinding and customBinding (converted with the online tool http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/default.aspx), i tried to set different variations of settings combinations but still get this error.

**any idea? canceling response certificate signing validation is also an option, but how do i set it??**

Comment: where are you calling this service from? win forms application?

Comment: "canceling response certificate signing validation is also an option"... Don't let Dominick Baier hear that!

Comment: yes, i developed tester win form app

Comment: yes mike :) i don't like this solution also, but how do i do it? i tried <security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" /> but i keep getting the same error...

Comment: I also have to ask, did you create your settings by copying and pasting them out of the WCF test client?

Comment: no Mike, i wrote it my self using WCF configuration editor, IBM DataPower doesn't provide WSDL with endpoint security policy, it just returning me the original WSDL which the internal hosting server provides.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

```
<system.serviceModel>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>

      <behavior name="DPSSLXDIG">
        <clientCredentials supportInteractive="false">
          <clientCertificate findValue="clientcert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          <serviceCertificate>
            <defaultCertificate findValue="servercert" storeName="TrustedPeople" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
          </serviceCertificate>
          <windows allowNtlm="false" allowedImpersonationLevel="None" />
          <httpDigest impersonationLevel="None" />
          <peer>
            <peerAuthentication revocationMode="NoCheck" />
          </peer>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>

    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>

    <customBinding>

      <binding name="DPSSLXDIG">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" />
        <security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex"
            requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
            requireSecurityContextCancellation="false">
          <secureConversationBootstrap />
        </security>
        <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" requireClientCertificate="true" />
      </binding>

    </customBinding>

  </bindings>
    <client>

      <endpoint address="https://myserver/webservice.asmx"
           behaviorConfiguration="DPSSLXDIG" binding="customBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="DPSSLXDIG" contract="serviceRef.smssoap"
           name="smsEndpoint">
        <identity>
          <dns value="servercert" />
        </identity>

      </endpoint>

    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Exactly, what solved it?!

Comment: just use this configuration

Answer (score 3):

Try using the custom binding with the following configuration:

```
<security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" />
```

Comment: i saw this in another post, tried it but it didn't help... :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and posted a solution to it here (for those coming here looking for an answer):

[WCF - Cannot find a token authenticator for X509SecurityToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435516/wcf-cannot-find-a-token-authenticator-for-x509securitytoken/38459294#38459294)

Based on the question, it appears to be the same solution:

1. Change `authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"` to `authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"`
2. Use `MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10`
3. In the generated client, add `ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign` to the `ServiceContractAttribute`. This avoids having the body encrypted.

Comment: @CodeCaster: This question is older than the linked one.. Should it still be marked as a duplicate? I can copy/paste the solution over, but that doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: The other one seems to have better answers than this one. I'll close this one.