# WCF - Cannot find a token authenticator for X509SecurityToken

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to call a 3rd party webservice and I've gotten to the point where I can actually see a response from the server in the Service Trace Viewer. However, I keep getting an exception from .NET:

```
Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type. 
Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.
```

My app.config looks like this (Thumbprints replaced by placeholders):

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="OteBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
          <defaultCertificate findValue="<ThumbprintPlaceholder1>" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
        <clientCertificate findValue="<ThumbprintPlaceholder2>" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
                requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
                enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
                allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true">

      </security>
      <httpsTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" requireClientCertificate="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://example.com:1443/xxx/someService/"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="OteBehavior"
    contract="ReportGasService.ReportGas" name="ReportGasEndpoint" />
</client>
```

Now, I've tried everything I could find regarding this exception.

1. Setting `authenticationMode` to `MutualCertificate`: Server responds 404
2. Setting `allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply`: No change

The reponse from the server contains:

```
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-1DE4B371623632132E1468838210413180294">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-1DE4B271123632132E1468838710413180295">
        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-1DE4B271523632132E1468833710413180293" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></wsse:Reference>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

Can I add the x508SecurityToken handler somewhere or otherwise ignore this error (is it safe to do so)

Exception Stack Trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver, IList`1 allowedTokenAuthenticators, SecurityTokenAuthenticator& usedTokenAuthenticator)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int32 position, Byte[] decryptedBuffer, SecurityToken encryptionToken, String idInEncryptedForm, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.StrictModeSecurityHeaderElementInferenceEngine.ExecuteProcessingPasses(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Does the above mean that it is serverside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Change `authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"` to `authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"`
2. Use `MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10`
3. In the generated client, add `ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign` to the `ServiceContractAttribute`. This avoids having the body encrypted.

I'm still not all the way through, but I believe it is merely a matter of getting the right certificate from the provider.

For others, here is how I create my proxy:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://xxx/yyy/someService/"));
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10, true);
securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;

var customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);
customBinding.Elements.Insert(0, securityElement);
var client = new ReportGasClient(customBinding, address);

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "BCC3929F9C115D4BCA1C697E2557B7FC7D6C8C8C");
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "87C3B5EE3913937459D2FFBF105ADBD1A578E823");
```

Please note I set the ValidationMode to None only in the sandbox environment. This should never be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Your values for `findValue` attribute are both incorrect. You should be putting the specific thumbprint value for the corresponding client-side certificates in the `app.config`.

You can view the certificate thumbprint values via the Certificates MMC add-in.

I would also double-check that client-side X509 certificates are required as normally, they are only required for server-side operation.

Comment: They are placeholders.. The certificates are correctly found - I am getting a response from the server. I did not receive a certificate from the provider, so I get it off of Chrome. Could that be an issue? The exception message seems to indicate not that the certificates are wrong - but that it cannot validate the token in the response.

Comment: How did you add the reference to the service? Normally the Add Service Reference wizard in VS gets the WCF configuration pretty much spot on... As I said, client certificates are not commonly used. Have you tried it without the client-side certificate?

Comment: I added it using the wizard. The service provider uses som SAP-based service which does not include all information in the wsdl (security part missing). And yes, it uses client certificates for authentication - there is no username/password.