# cannot find a token authenticatorfor the system.Identitymodel.tokens.X509SecurityTOken token type - .net core WCF client

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting an error when calling WCF service from .net core 3.1 client. i used connected services to import the WSDl and generated client code. When calling the service, i am getting below error. Cannot find a token authenticator for the System.Identitymodel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.

In .net framework client, i had property under security called allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = true. But i don't see this here.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435516. Have you tried all the steps there?

Comment: no. it is not a duplicate. i have checked that link. it is .net framework. In .net core 3.1, and wcf 4.8 libraries, there is no mutualcertificateandbindingelement. it is available in .net framework only.